# python lxml different result on windows and linux

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree

Linux

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> html='''<td><a href=''>a1</a></td>
... <td><a href=''>a2</a></td>
... '''
>>> p=etree.HTML(html)
>>> a=p.xpath("//a[1]")
>>> for i in a:
...    print i.text
... 
a1
a2
```

windows.

```
>>> html='''<td><a href=''>a1</a></td>
... <td><a href=''>a2</a></td>
... '''
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> p=etree.HTML(html)
>>> a=p.xpath("//a[1]")
>>> for i in a:
...    print i.text
...
a1
>>> b=p.xpath("//a[2]")
>>> for i in b:
...    print i.text
...
a2
```

In Windows, I can easily to use `a[1]` and `a[2]` to get those two value.
But in Linux, xpath `//a[1]` get those two link text together.

This make the program not so compatible in those OS. I have to modify code on different OS.
Is it a lxml module bug ? Any solution for this ?

Comment: Please clarify what your question is, what the expected output is, and what you are getting.

Comment: New on stackoverflow editor when post. You may see my incomplete question when I am still trying the editing. Now my question has been updated.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on Linux. When I run your code, it only prints `a1` as expected. I have `lxml-3.3.5`.

Comment: I reproduced this on linux with `lmxl 2.3`

Comment: Do you have the same versions of lxml and python on windows and linux?

Comment: my lxml version on linux and windows are both `lxml 3.3.5`

Comment: Testing on MS Windows in Python 2.7.3 32 bit and `lxml.etree.__version__ == "2.3.0"` I get the same result as on Linux, that is, it return 2 elements.
Testing on Windows with lxml upgraded to 3.3.5 it returns just 1 element. This is wierd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm the same result on Linux as you report. It returns a list of two elements instead of 1 single element.

## What is xpath `//a[1]` asking for

It is asking for any `a` element which is first within it's context.

As you have `a` element embedded inside  of `td`, `td` is the context for calculating the position and there are two occurrences of such situation.

Changing xpath to `"(//a)[1]"` resolves the problem.

Quoting from [MSDN on Operators and Special Characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256122%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The filter pattern operators ([]) have a higher precedence than the path operators (/ and //). For example, the expression //comment()[3] selects all comments with an index equal to 3 relative to the comment's parent anywhere in the document. This differs from the expression (//comment())[3], which selects the third comment from the set of all comments relative to the parent. The first expression can return more than one comment, while the latter can return only one comment.

## Downgrade broken Windows lxml version 3.3.5

xpath `//a[1]` returning only one element of provided document is simply wrong and shall be reported to lxml authors.

Status of lxml on diferent platfoms and OS:

- Win: lxml 2.3.0 - OK
- Win: lxml 3.3.5 - BUG
- Lin: lxml 3.3.5 - OK
- Lin: lxml 2.3.0 - OK

To make your solution portable, you shall require `lxml==2.3.0` as this version behaves on Windows as well as on Linux correctly (there might be another version working well on both platforms, I did not test more).

### Bonus - test suite

Assuming you have installed `nose`

```
$ pip install nose
```

You can use following `test_xpath.py`:

```
from lxml import etree
import nose

print "=================================="
print "lxml version: ", etree.__version__
print "=================================="

def test_html():
    html_str = """
    <td><a href=''>a1</a></td>
    <td><a href=''>a2</a></td>
    """
    doc = etree.HTML(html_str.strip())
    elms = doc.xpath("//a[1]")
    assert len(elms) == 2, """xpath `//a[1]` shall return 2 elements"""
    assert all(elm.tag == "a" for elm in elms), "all returned elements shall be `a`"
    assert elms[0].text == "a1"
    assert elms[1].text == "a2"

def test_xml():
    xml_str = """
    <root>
        <td><a href=''>a1</a></td>
        <td><a href=''>a2</a></td>
    </root>
    """
    doc = etree.fromstring(xml_str.strip())
    elms = doc.xpath("//a[1]")
    assert len(elms) == 2, """xpath `//a[1]` shall return 2 elements"""
    assert all(elm.tag == "a" for elm in elms), "all returned elements shall be `a`"
    assert elms[0].text == "a1"
    assert elms[1].text == "a2"

nose.main()
```

and perform a test quickly:

```
$ python test_xpath.py  -v
==================================
lxml version:  2.3.0
==================================
test_xpath.test_html ... ok
test_xpath.test_xml ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

OK
```

Comment: Can you explain why this makes a difference in Linux vs windows?

Comment: Thanks! For solving my problem itself, I just use ` a=p.xpath("//td//a")` , then in Lin and Win, both return the same result.
And for dive to deep, I think you have explain and also get tested by other people, this should be a bug. I'll try if I can report to the author.